# Pytest Teardown Fixture

Tags: python, pytest

I need to delete some folders created for testing.
In the main test folder, I created the a file `test_teardown.py` with the following content.

```py
import shutil
import pytest


@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def teardown():
    yield
    shutil.rmtree('tmp')
```

Yet, the `tmp` folder is not deleted after the testing session is completed. Am I using the fixture incorrectly?

File structure

```
+-- Project folder
|   +-- tests
|   |   +-- __init__.py
|   |   +-- test_teardown.py
|   |   +-- Unit
|   |   |   +-- __init__.py
|   |   |   +-- test_moretests.py
```

Comment: You need to set the fixture to `autouse=True` if you want it to be automatically involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MrBean Bremen

Adding `autouse=True` to the wrapper ensures that it's automatically involved.
Do make sure that your `test_teardown.py` is included in the used test folder.

Wrapper:

```
@pytest.fixture(scope='session', autouse=True)
def teardown():
    yield
    shutil.rmtree('tmp')
```